# how to return a function name

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm new in here and I want to ask for a help.

Current Code:

```
private con0 as new ADODB.connection
private con1 as new ADODB.connection
private con2 as new ADODB.connection
```

preferred Code:

```
private function con(Byval i as integer) as ADODB.connection
 ' Code here
End sub
```

how to make it work as like this below.

```
 con(1) as ADODB.Connection
```

to remove the multiple con0, con2, con3
because if I just used the code

```
public con as ADODB.Connection
```

in multiple commands but I need to make the first connection to stay open, I got error of cannot do when con is open. But I don't want to use the Current Code.

Comment: That's not how it works. If you want to be able to access items by sequential numeric index then use an array. If you want to be able to access items by arbitrary key then use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: I just realised that you have tagged this question VB.NET and VB6. It can't be both. If you had read the tag descriptions then you'd have seen where it specifically states not to use each for the other language. Work out what language you're using and remove the irrelevant tag. You're wasting people's time by spamming tags because you're indicating to people that a question is relevant to them when it probably isn't.

Comment: Looks like this is VB6, not VB.Net? If so please remove the `vb6` tag

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
Dim con(2) As ADODB.Connection
```

It declares an array with three items. And I *really* hope this really is vb6 rather than VB.Net. There's *no possible good reason* to use the old `ADODB` types in .Net. If you have .Net, you want this:

```
Dim con(2) As System.Data.DbConnection
```

Also, it's probably a mistake to have more than one connection object. If you don't know what connection pooling is, you might want to read up on that first, because the ADO libraries already manage a pool of connections for you automatically.